# d3 error with manual zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3 v4.

I'm implementing a zoom on an area graph using the following [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). My zoom is registered as such:

```
    // Zoom Components
    zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff*12])
            .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

With my zoom method looking like this:

```
function zoomed(){
    t = d3.event.transform;
    console.log(t);
    ...
}
```

When naturally zooming with the wheel, the `console` spits out:

```
{
    k:1.0097512975966858
    x:-1.9210056265470996
    y:-1.004383652458642
}
```

I'm using a `TimeScale` and I want to zoom in and translate to a certain period of time. For example, I may only want to show 7 days as my x1 and x2, so i calculate scale factor of k and then calculate tx value to translate to a certain area. I
created a manual zoom method to trigger a manual zoom. With the following code:

```
function manualZoom(){
    var outerRightDay,
        thirtyBeforeOuter,
        k,
        tx;
        // Get outer right day
        outerRightDay = moment(xScale.domain()[1]);
        // Get 30 days before
        thirtyBeforeOuter = moment(outerRightDay).subtract(31,'days');
        // Get scale k
        k = width / (xScale(outerRightDay) - xScale(thirtyBeforeOuter));
        // Get transform value

        svg.call(zoom.scaleBy, k);
        tx = 0 - k * xScale(thirtyBeforeOuter);
        svg.call(zoom.translateBy,tx);
}
```

After running this, the zoomed method spits out:

```
{
    k:1.0097512975966858 //a good number
    x:-1.9210056265470996 //a good number
    y:NAN //this is an issue!!!!
}
```

It works with mouse wheel, buy on touch devices. My `y` is `NAN` and stops me from zooming in on a touch device. How can I calculate `ty` to supply it to [`zoom.translateBy()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_translateBy).

I have included a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codekhalifah/m2zbL32j/7/) here.

Comment: can you give a working fiddle..

Comment: Yes let me put one together.

Comment: @Cyril .  I've added a JsFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only use transform rescale on x-axis (in `zoomed` function), you don't care about the value of `ty`. Just pass a value to `translateBy`, it won't be `NaN` and it will work:

```
svg.call(zoom.translateBy,tx,0);
```

Why `ty` is `NaN` with your code? `zoom.translateBy` calls `transform.translate` function, its [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/src/transform.js#L13) is:

```
translate: function(x, y) {
  return x === 0 & y === 0 ? this : new Transform(this.k, this.x + this.k * x, this.y + this.k * y);
}
```

So if `y` is `undefined`, `this.y + this.k * y` will be evaluated as `NaN`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I overlooked this, but I'm using d3 with Ionic 2 / Angular 2 and doing some pretty complex graphs, so I guess as complexities come, the small things are missed. Thanks alot!